# HTTP status code for update and delete?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

What status code should I set for `UPDATE` (`PUT`) and `DELETE` (e.g. product successfully updated)?

Answer (score 2749, accepted):

For a **PUT** request: **HTTP 200**, **HTTP 204** should imply "resource updated successfully". **HTTP 201** if the **PUT** request created a new resource.

For a **DELETE** request: **HTTP 200** or **HTTP 204** should imply "resource deleted successfully".

**HTTP 202** can also be returned by either operation and would imply that the instruction was accepted by the server, but not fully applied yet. It's possible that the operation fails later, so the client shouldn't fully assume that it was  success.

A client that receives a status code it doesn't recognize, but it's starting with 2 should treat it as a 200 OK.

> **[PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3.4)**
>
> If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request.

> **[DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3.5)**
>
> A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an entity describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action has not yet been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been enacted but the response does not include an entity.

Source: [IETF: RFC-9110 Method Definitions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3)

> **HTTP 200 OK:** Standard response for successful HTTP
> requests. The actual response will
> depend on the request method used.
>
> **HTTP 204 No Content:** The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content

Source: [List of HTTP status codes: 2xx Success](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)

Comment: Very useful post! However I am wondering what should be the HTTP status code is the request sent by the client is valid (DELETE http://mySite/entity/123) and the entity to delete does not exist.

Comment: @Martin: In that case, the service should return an HTTP 404. Strictly speaking, a DELETE or a GET request for a resource that does not exist is **not** a "valid" request - ie. the client should not re-attempt that request because it will never succeed... The HTTP protocol defines 2 categories of problems - those with a 4xx status code, where the client must modify the request before retrying it, and those with a 5xx status code, which indicate that the service ran into trouble and the client should/could retry the same exact request without changing it.

Comment: @Martin, Daniel
I think you are looking at what a successful call for DELETE is.  If you look at DELETE as "make sure the resource is deleted", then it is successful whether or not the resource existed before the call or not.

Comment: @JeffMartin That may be so from the standpoint of the user, but as far as the server is concerned, if the resource does not exist, the server should return 404.

Comment: Ceph returns 201 for successful creation with PUT.

Comment: @Randolpho, Idempotence is all about getting the same result whether you invoke an operation once or multiple times. The client is asking you to ensure that the resource is deleted. What's the benefit of returning 404? Why does it need to know either way? Now the client logic has to handle two separate response codes instead of one.

Comment: @Gili I'm not sure I understand the question. 404 has a specific meaning: the request was bad because the resource did not exist. Allowing a success code gives the client the incorrect belief that the resource *did* exist and was deleted. And a client sure better handle *all* possible response codes than just one if it wants to be a robust and non-error-prone client.

Comment: @Gili: perhaps [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications) will explain better: *Methods PUT and DELETE are defined to be idempotent... note that idempotence refers to the state of the system after the request has completed, so while the action the server takes (e.g. deleting a record) or the response code it returns may be different on subsequent requests, the system state will be the same every time.*

Comment: @Randolpho, if you user wants to check the existence of a resource it should use `GET` or `If-Match` headers. It is my understanding that `DELETE` is equivalent to `rm` on Linux: delete the file if it exists, otherwise do nothing. The only time `DELETE` should fail is if the resource exists but it cannot be deleted for some reason (e.g. you don't have sufficient permissions).

Comment: Guys, don't forget that if you send a 204 as response to a successful PUT, you do not receive any content back. In my case, I didn't realise this (even as the http status code states it is a NO content :) ). So if you want to send a success message back, I would recommend a 206 which sends partial content. Otherwise send a 200

Comment: PUT could be 201 if the resource did not exist and has therefore been created.

Comment: @Gili, did you mean `rm -f` on Linux? `rm` will give you an error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: DanielVassallo, @Randolpho I disagree. With a PUT or a DELETE the client is asking for a certain state to be present on the server. DELETE is not about the deletion but rather "I want this resource to not exist". With a 2xx response, the server informs the client that its request was successful, the state has been attained. By sending a 404, you are "overloading" the status code to inform the client about what the state on the server was before its request, and what the server had to do to attain that state. If it helps your particular business case, go for it, but 2xx is more correct.

Comment: Keep in mind a 204 response, can not have any content in the body! 

"The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields." 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: There is a separate Q&A that revolves around what should be the status of subsequent DELETE calls. Spoiler: the answers mostly agree on 404 as idempotency is defined in term of effects on the server.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6439416/2157640

Answer (score 1007):

Short answer: for both PUT and DELETE, you should send either 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content).

Long answer: here's a complete decision diagram (click to magnify).

[image: HTTP 1.1 decision diagram]

Source: https://github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram

Comment: The diagram is amazing. Is there a higher resolution version for printing out?

Comment: In the context of POST of an existing resource, another SO discussion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists) suggests to send 409 Conflict or 302 Found instead of appending the content.

Comment: Maybe this? https://raw.github.com/andreineculau/http-decision-diagram/master/v4/http-decision-diagram-v4.png High res and pretty nice

Comment: I'm curious if the 204 and 200 response after a delete occurs should be reversed, and if they are correct as is, why?
Deleted? -> Response includes an entity? -> yes -> 204 No Content; no -> 200 OK

Comment: 501 and 405 should both be checked before 401 and 403. Updated version has it correct: https://raw.github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram/master/httpdd.png

Comment: @docksteaderluke Awesome stuff, but why there is no POST code there?

Comment: @doremi: [RFC 5789](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) suggests that (like most HTTP methods) it's up to the developer.  However, it also explicitly states that responding with 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) is completely appropriate.

Comment: I think "Deleted? / Response includes an entity? / Yes & No" labels should be swapped? No response entity should lead to 204.

Comment: This diagram is awesome. But he don't say 200 for put and post  ... for put and post it should be 201 in most case ( rest full application and you can get your entity with a get server/entity/{id} ) but it's ok for 200 on DELETE

Comment: Updated the diagram to the latest version as it was repeatedly referenced in comments as more accurate. Also, added a link to the original source.

Comment: This diagram is beautiful. Does anybody know what tool was used to create it? We need to generate some of these.

Comment: @joshuapinter To answer myself, it looks like Omnigraffle was used to create this graph, I think: https://github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram/blob/master/httpdd.graffle

Comment: @JoshuaPinter this was created with aiSee. Sadly the tool is no longer available as a standalone product. I used to work with graphs a lot back in the day, and no other tool was up to the task. Maybe some are now, but I wouldn't know. It's been ten years. Time flies.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter actually I withdraw that previous comment. I only just noticed that the image has since been replaced by a different one with a link to its source.

Comment: Keep in mind a 204 response, can not have any content in the body! 

"The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields." 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Is there some documentation on the vocabulary used in the diagram? Such as what terms like ["to_content" in N8](https://github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram/blob/master/httpdd.fsm.json#L2950) mean?

Comment: first link is broken

Answer (score 185):

Here are some Tips:

**DELETE**

> - **200** (if you want send some additional data in the Response) or **204** (recommended).
> - **202** Operation deleted has not been committed yet.
> - If there's nothing to delete, use **204** *or* **404** (DELETE operation is idempotent, delete an already deleted item is *operation successful*, so you can return **204**, but it's true that idempotent doesn't necessarily imply the same response)
>
> Other errors:
>
> - **400** *Bad Request* (Malformed syntax or a bad query is *strange* but possible).
> - **401** *Unauthorized* Authentication failure
> - **403** *Forbidden*: Authorization failure or invalid Application ID.
> - **405** *Not Allowed*. Sure.
> - **409** *Resource Conflict* can be possible in complex systems.
> - And **501**, **502** in case of errors.

**PUT**

> If you're updating an element of a collection
>
> - **200/204** with the same reasons as DELETE above.
> - **202** if the operation has not been commited yet.
>
> The referenced element doesn't exists:
>
> - PUT can be **201** (if you created the element because that is your behaviour)
> - **404** If you don't want to create elements via PUT.
> - **400** *Bad Request* (Malformed syntax or a bad query more common than in case of DELETE).
> - **401** *Unauthorized*
> - **403** *Forbidden*: Authentication failure or invalid Application ID.
> - **405** *Not Allowed*. Sure.
> - **409** *Resource Conflict* can be possible in complex systems, as in DELETE.
> - **422** *Unprocessable entity* It helps to distinguish between a "Bad request" (e.g. malformed XML/JSON) and invalid field values
> - And **501**, **502** in case of errors.

Comment: This answer is made up almost entirely of two large quotes, but there's no attribution. Where are you quoting from?

Comment: Is 204 a proper status to return for a PUT request, if the state is not changed effectively? For example, you ask to deactivate a user but the user is already inactive.

Comment: The PUT request is idempotent, so you can return a 204, because the object *has changed* in the system. PUT is not PATCH, so you're not sure what field do you want to change. You can send back a 501 - 502, if your design needs to know if the object was **exactly** the same as the object in the request but... I don't really like it..  I prefer 204 or, if you want to deactivate an user, without changing more fields, maybe you can use PATCH.

Comment: I'd add HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity. It helps to distinguish between a "Bad request" (e.g. malformed XML/JSON) and invalid field values.

Comment: @AlfonsoTienda what to return on DELETE when parent resource is missing? (e.g. if we receive DELETE {{restful-api-base}}/departments/1/colleagues/2 should we say 404 no such department 1 or say 204 deleted even though department 1 is non existent and we are trying to delete the colleague 2 of it)

Comment: I think this is a question of design, but I should return 404 in this case

Answer (score 20):

RFC 2616 describes [which status codes to use](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

And no, it's **not** always 200.

Answer (score 17):

***Here's some status code, which you should know for your kind of knowledge.***

### 1XX Information Responses

> - **100** *Continue*
> - **101** *Switching Protocols*
> - **102** *Processing*
> - **103** *Early Hints*

### 2XX Success

> - **200** *OK*
> - **201** *Created*
> - **202** *Accepted*
> - **203** *Non-Authoritative Information*
> - **204** *No Content*
> - **205** *Reset Content*
> - **206** *Partial Content*
> - **207** *Multi-Status*
> - **208** *Already Reported*
> - **226** *IM Used*

### 3XX Redirection

> - **300** *Multiple Choices*
> - **301** *Moved Permanently*
> - **302** *Found*
> - **303** *See Other*
> - **304** *Not Modified*
> - **305** *Use Proxy*
> - **306** *Switch Proxy*
> - **307** *Temporary Redirect*
> - **308** *Permanent Redirect*

### 4XX Client errors

> - **400** *Bad Request*
> - **401** *Unauthorized*
> - **402** *Payment Required*
> - **403** *Forbidden*
> - **404** *Not Found*
> - **405** *Method Not Allowed*
> - **406** *Not Acceptable*
> - **407** *Proxy Authentication Required*
> - **408** *Request Timeout*
> - **409** *Conflict*
> - **410** *Gone*
> - **411** *Length Required*
> - **412** *Precondition Failed*
> - **413** *Payload Too Large*
> - **414** *URI Too Long*
> - **415** *Unsupported Media Type*
> - **416** *Range Not Satisfiable*
> - **417** *Expectation Failed*
> - **418** *I'm a teapot*
> - **420** *Method Failure*
> - **421** *Misdirected Request*
> - **422** *Unprocessable Entity*
> - **423** *Locked*
> - **424** *Failed Dependency*
> - **426** *Upgrade Required*
> - **428** *Precondition Required*
> - **429** *Too Many Requests*
> - **431** *Request Header Fields Too Large*
> - **451** *Unavailable For Legal Reasons*

### 5XX Server errors

> - **500** *Internal Server error*
> - **501** *Not Implemented*
> - **502** *Bad Gateway*
> - **503** *Service Unavailable*
> - **504** *gateway Timeout*
> - **505** *Http version not supported*
> - **506** *Varient Also negotiate*
> - **507** *Insufficient Storage*
> - **508** *Loop Detected*
> - **510** *Not Extended*
> - **511** *Network Authentication Required*

Answer (score 11):

In addition to 200 and 204, [205 (Reset Content)](http://httpstatus.es/205) could be a valid response.

> The server has fulfilled the request and the user agent SHOULD reset the document view which caused the request to be sent ... [e.g.] clearing of the form in which the input is given.

Answer (score 6):

Since the question delves into if **DELETE** "should" return **200** vs **204** it is worth considering that some people recommend returning an entity with links so the preference is for **200**.

> "Instead of returning 204 (No Content), the API should be helpful and
>   suggest places to go. In this example I think one obvious link to
>   provide is to" *'somewhere.com/container/' (minus 'resource')* "- the container from which
>   the client just deleted a resource. Perhaps the client wishes to
>   delete more resources, so that would be a helpful link."

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/30/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-204-responses/

> If a client encounters a 204 response, it can either give up, go to
>   the entry point of the API, or go back to the previous resource it
>   visited. Neither option is particularly good.

Personally I would not say 204 is wrong (neither does the author; he says "annoying") because good caching at the client side has many benefits. Best is to be consistent either way.

Answer (score 3):

In June 2014 [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) obsoletes RFC2616.
If you are doing REST over HTTP then [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) describes exactly what behaviour is expected from GET, PUT, POST and DELETE

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "VALIDATON_ERROR": {
        "code": 512,
        "message": "Validation error"
    },
    "CONTINUE": {
        "code": 100,
        "message": "Continue"
    },
    "SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS": {
        "code": 101,
        "message": "Switching Protocols"
    },
    "PROCESSING": {
        "code": 102,
        "message": "Processing"
    },
    "OK": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "CREATED": {
        "code": 201,
        "message": "Created"
    },
    "ACCEPTED": {
        "code": 202,
        "message": "Accepted"
    },
    "NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION": {
        "code": 203,
        "message": "Non Authoritative Information"
    },
    "NO_CONTENT": {
        "code": 204,
        "message": "No Content"
    },
    "RESET_CONTENT": {
        "code": 205,
        "message": "Reset Content"
    },
    "PARTIAL_CONTENT": {
        "code": 206,
        "message": "Partial Content"
    },
    "MULTI_STATUS": {
        "code": 207,
        "message": "Multi-Status"
    },
    "MULTIPLE_CHOICES": {
        "code": 300,
        "message": "Multiple Choices"
    },
    "MOVED_PERMANENTLY": {
        "code": 301,
        "message": "Moved Permanently"
    },
    "MOVED_TEMPORARILY": {
        "code": 302,
        "message": "Moved Temporarily"
    },
    "SEE_OTHER": {
        "code": 303,
        "message": "See Other"
    },
    "NOT_MODIFIED": {
        "code": 304,
        "message": "Not Modified"
    },
    "USE_PROXY": {
        "code": 305,
        "message": "Use Proxy"
    },
    "TEMPORARY_REDIRECT": {
        "code": 307,
        "message": "Temporary Redirect"
    },
    "PERMANENT_REDIRECT": {
        "code": 308,
        "message": "Permanent Redirect"
    },
    "BAD_REQUEST": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    },
    "UNAUTHORIZED": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Unauthorized"
    },
    "PAYMENT_REQUIRED": {
        "code": 402,
        "message": "Payment Required"
    },
    "FORBIDDEN": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    },
    "NOT_FOUND": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED": {
        "code": 405,
        "message": "Method Not Allowed"
    },
    "NOT_ACCEPTABLE": {
        "code": 406,
        "message": "Not Acceptable"
    },
    "PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED": {
        "code": 407,
        "message": "Proxy Authentication Required"
    },
    "REQUEST_TIMEOUT": {
        "code": 408,
        "message": "Request Timeout"
    },
    "CONFLICT": {
        "code": 409,
        "message": "Conflict"
    },
    "GONE": {
        "code": 410,
        "message": "Gone"
    },
    "LENGTH_REQUIRED": {
        "code": 411,
        "message": "Length Required"
    },
    "PRECONDITION_FAILED": {
        "code": 412,
        "message": "Precondition Failed"
    },
    "REQUEST_TOO_LONG": {
        "code": 413,
        "message": "Request Entity Too Large"
    },
    "REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG": {
        "code": 414,
        "message": "Request-URI Too Long"
    },
    "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE": {
        "code": 415,
        "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
    },
    "REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE": {
        "code": 416,
        "message": "Requested Range Not Satisfiable"
    },
    "EXPECTATION_FAILED": {
        "code": 417,
        "message": "Expectation Failed"
    },
    "IM_A_TEAPOT": {
        "code": 418,
        "message": "I'm a teapot"
    },
    "INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ON_RESOURCE": {
        "code": 419,
        "message": "Insufficient Space on Resource"
    },
    "METHOD_FAILURE": {
        "code": 420,
        "message": "Method Failure"
    },
    "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY": {
        "code": 422,
        "message": "Unprocessable Entity"
    },
    "LOCKED": {
        "code": 423,
        "message": "Locked"
    },
    "FAILED_DEPENDENCY": {
        "code": 424,
        "message": "Failed Dependency"
    },
    "PRECONDITION_REQUIRED": {
        "code": 428,
        "message": "Precondition Required"
    },
    "TOO_MANY_REQUESTS": {
        "code": 429,
        "message": "Too Many Requests"
    },
    "REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE": {
        "code": 431,
        "message": "Request Header Fields Too"
    },
    "UNAVAILABLE_FOR_LEGAL_REASONS": {
        "code": 451,
        "message": "Unavailable For Legal Reasons"
    },
    "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    },
    "NOT_IMPLEMENTED": {
        "code": 501,
        "message": "Not Implemented"
    },
    "BAD_GATEWAY": {
        "code": 502,
        "message": "Bad Gateway"
    },
    "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE": {
        "code": 503,
        "message": "Service Unavailable"
    },
    "GATEWAY_TIMEOUT": {
        "code": 504,
        "message": "Gateway Timeout"
    },
    "HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED": {
        "code": 505,
        "message": "HTTP Version Not Supported"
    },
    "INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE": {
        "code": 507,
        "message": "Insufficient Storage"
    },
    "NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED": {
        "code": 511,
        "message": "Network Authentication Required"
    }
}
```

Comment: 512 seems a bit off, it's not standardized and I would assume a validation error being in the 4xx range (like 422). Where did you get this list?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `200 OK` and `201 Created` are the best suited for a successful `PUT` request.

For `DELETE` method, `202 Accepted` and `204 No Content` would be the best choice.