# What HTTP error code to return for name already taken?

Tags: http, error-code

I'm doing an AJAX call to set the username. If the username is already taken what HTTP code should I return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HTTP response code for "This email is already registered"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269040/which-http-response-code-for-this-email-is-already-registered)

Answer (score 43):

You can use 409 Conflict.

Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the current state.

Comment: 200 with an error message violates the purpose of all different HTTP error status codes.

Comment: According to the [**Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry**](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)  
**2xx** - The action was successfully received, understood, and accepted 
 
**4xx** - The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled

Therefore 200 is not appropriate for the answer suggested

Answer (score 14):

I would choose 422 Unprocessable Entity .   Lot's of rails developers use this for all validation errors.

And yes, it is totally appropriate to evaluate the error status and render the error message with javascript.  This is especially useful, if you are using the same actions for an API.  Then your ajax requests are accessing the same API that you would expose to other developers.

Comment: would this be applicable to when the user is registering with pass too short, incorrect chars. invalid email etc? Thanks!

Comment: Yes - it means that what the browser is sending is in conflict with a constraint on the system.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me that stumble across this question, it seems to me the correct answer should be:

- 403 / Forbidden.

As you can see in the definition below taken from the link sent by @rationalboss [List of HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors)

> 403 Forbidden:
> The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action. This may be due to the user not having the necessary permissions for a resource or needing an account of some sort, or attempting a prohibited action (e.g. creating a duplicate record where only one is allowed). This code is also typically used if the request provided authentication by answering the WWW-Authenticate header field challenge, but the server did not accept that authentication. The request should not be repeated.

Answer (score -3):

There is no rule here, it is up to you. However, as @rationalboss said, it makes sense to return 200 with a message since the HTTP request has succeeded, the error is unrelated to the request.

400 errors mean the request itself was not correct in some way, like wrong verb or missing parameters.

The question here is about interpretation, both from software clients and from humans and it might be better to stay away from error codes when there is no HTTP error.

Comment: I disagree, but like you said it's a matter of opinion. To me, an error completing the request warrants an error code. I don't want a client to be checking for the details in the response to know something was wrong. If I return OK, it means it has succeeded. Any errors completing the request should fall under the 400 category, unless it is an actual server exception, case in which it goes to the 500, but never 200.

Answer (score -5):

There is no HTTP Code for name already taken. Please see [List of HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

If you are using AJAX calls to set the username, why not just show the error in HTML? This is more user-friendly as your visitors would know what the actual error means, instead of seeing some 4XX code.

Comment: i was going to catch the 4xx code with jquery and display a user friendly error message.

Comment: you are not limited to catching things with http status codes. you can catch the error messages instead. Check the [jQuery API on $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The `success` handler should help you, just check the examples in the API.

Comment: As I commented below, 200 is for success. Errors completing requests warrant an error status code. I hope Ryan hasn't gone out of his way to return 200s when the request has failed - that's a bad idea all around.