# 422 or 409 status code for existing email during signup

Tags: rest, api, http

I am building RESTful API and I have come across a situation. During user sign up, if the email already exists then between `422` and `409` which http response code makes sense?
I have browsed through similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269040/which-http-response-code-for-this-email-is-already-registered) and the accepted answer is from the year 2012. Does the answer still hold good? Examples would be of great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP response code for POST when resource already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists)

Answer (score 21):

You may not find a *very definitive answer* to this question, once both [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) and [`422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) would be suitable for this situation (I would go for [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) though).

For any of them, you must ensure that a payload describing the problem is sent back to the client.

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Comment: `409` is for `PUT`/`POST` when you use  `ETag`. It is not designed to be an indicator of a business error.

Comment: @gavenkoa I think `ETag` usage is more connected to `412 Precondition Failed` and `304 Not Modified`

Comment: `409` is a `Conflict` for `PUT`, like 2 requests concurrently update same entity, one succeeds, another `409` because ETag has been updated. Some frameworks/libs/server might emit 409 automatically, for that reason I'd prefer `422` - there is a guaranty no one except my code emit it, so monitoring tool reports won't be false positive (because `409` is shared with some predefined HTTP/RFC semantic).

Comment: Had the same choice between 409 & 422, and also went with 409 at the end. Put the rationale in what I hope can be named as a definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70371989

Comment: @gavenkoa `409` is not just for a `PUT` request. It can be for any request. The RFC just says it's most likely to occur with a `PUT`. It's about state.

Answer (score 5):

I think `409` is most appropriate in this described example as the request is conflicting with an already existing registration.

For example, if the service couldn't accept a .de domain based email address; `422` seems preferable. This example would also not qualify for a `400` as a .de domain would be valid syntax.