# Why does axios not get the express response with status(409)?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest, express

I use axios to post username and password to express backend. In the backend I check whether the username already exists, if the username already exists I send json to the frontend. I tried sending `res.status(409).json({username_exists: true})`, but I got an error. Then I tried sending exactly the same response but with the status code 200 and it worked.

Why does `status(409)` give an error?

I read here on stackoverflow that the status code should be 409 if the username already exists, which status code to send so that the frontend receives the json?

Comment: Define "got an error". A 400+ is an error by definition--are you asking about how to process error status code with Axios?

Comment: @DaveNewton This is the error code: Error: Request failed with status code 409

Comment: Is it possible to send json with an error status code? @DaveNewton

Comment: Yes, because that is what happened. I'm asking what specifically you want to be able to do, e.g., Axios defaults to erroring on... errors. You can update the `validateStatus` function to work around this. (There are other ways as well--searching the web for something like "axios error access response" will be helpful.)

Comment: I would like to point out this showing errors like this is a big security issue, as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531069/1710359

Comment: I know, but I don't have any other way to tell the user that the username is taken. Is there any other way to do it? @gear4

Comment: Axios treats all 4XX codes as errors (because they are) To improve error handling, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors

Comment: @Jack774 you should be sending a generic error (400 or whatever) that something is wrong (never be specific about something being incorrect)