# What HTTP error code should I use when trying to insert an already existing object?

Tags: rest, http, error-code

I'm designing a REST API. Some methods of this API are used to insert new data using the POST method. I'm wondering what error code to return when the insertion would result in duplicate data being inserted? I tried looking at the error code reference, but being quite new to REST and HTTP I'm not sure which one to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP response code for POST when resource already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`409 Conflict` seems appropriate for that case.

The [W3C status code definitions document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> **10.4.10 409 Conflict**
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.