# Prevent posting an object if its id exists in the api

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

So, I have a button that posts an object with "id", "name", "description" properties to the api. What I want to achieve is to prevent posting any other object if they have the same "id" of the object posted before.
Is that even possible?

Comment: You would have to do a GET to the API to make sure the `object.id` you are sending isn't already there. What kind of API is it?

Comment: Or you can reply to the POST call with `409 Conflict` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists.

Comment: I'm just testing this on a fake json-server

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the server needs to check if the ID already exists and if so return you a proper HTTP error-code you handle in your client-side fetch code.

In addition you can keep track of what you already sent to the server (for this workstation only) by storing the already sent Ids vor example in the [local state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class), a Redux state or in another global object. You can also use IoC container like [Inversify](http://inversify.io) to hold a singelton at hand which can do the bookkeeping of already sent IDs. There are many options. Let us know if you have any more specific requirement or library already in use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your API you can reject any `POST` requests with the same `id`.

If you do not have control over the API then you have to handle that check explicitly yourself. For example you could store it in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and before doing the `fetch` call you can check if it already exists.

If what you are asking is if there is a pre-defined way to do this via `fetch`, then no there is not.