# What to return with a 409 conflict?

Tags: api, rest, http, fastapi

Let's say I have a registration page with a user where they create a new account. If the user is already registered by that email, I'll return a `409 CONFLICT` status. However, I'm not quite sure what the proper content is required to return with that -- for example, do I return that user object? Do I return nothing? Do I return a text message? Here is what I have thus far:

```
@app.post("/users", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    # ... some logic
    try:
        db.commit()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
        return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)

    # ...
```

Are there any reference APIs that show what is supposed to be returned with a `409` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTTP [specification](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.409):

> This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. **The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists) question for a discussion what code should be used and what should be returned.

Comment: thanks, are there any example APIs you can point to that would show a request that could be emulated here that would return a 409? Such as Github or StackOverflow or whatever where you try and create a duplicate user account?