# REST API - What should my post return

Tags: api, rest

Here is a small description about what I am trying to do

1. Build a set of APIs for online game play
2. my GET API i want to return all open games (list of gameIds)
   GET /api/games/
3. my POST API i want to create a new game 
   POST /api/games/

My question is what should my POST API return. Ideally I would want client to know the gameId of the newly created game, so that all operations specific to the game can then use following syntax /api/games/gameId

Any suggestions, on how I communicate this gameId back to client?

Comment: You could just return the uri for the newly created resource, in the location header, with 201 created

Comment: One option is to include not only the ID, but the full URL for subsequent access, an idea which goes by the rather lengthy name of HATEOAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return 201, Created as the response code. The location header should contain the URL of the newly created resource (ie. /api/games/new_game_id).

Full details can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268707/what-rest-put-post-delete-calls-should-return-by-a-convention), in particular the reference to the RFC.