# Local interface and REST web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

If I use the same interface for a local EJB and web service EJB as shown below I can't use the same create method. What should I do? Should I create another interface for the web service methods or doing as below? Or are there better alternatives?

```
@Local
@Path("questions")
public interface QuestionServiceLocal {

    @POST
    Response create(JAXBElement<Question> question);
    void create(Question question);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your use case ? Do you want to create a Restful Web service API ?
Then read about JAX-RS specification
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html
ALTERNATIVES :-
Several libraries/frameworks as follows could help you develop restful services easily,

1. [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) - Popular JAX-RS implementation.
2. [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) - Reference implementation of JAX-RS spec.
3. [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) - Not so popular but one of the viable option.
4. [Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379485/restful-on-play-framework) - Personal favorite and very easy to pickup.
5. [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/) - New entrant, from guys who created Yammer !