# How to host a java RESTful web service for android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I am looking to develop a java REST web service to work with my android app that I am also developing and I have been trying to look for the best option to host the service and everything I find seems to lead me in a different direction.

Can anyone give me advice on what the best way to host a java REST web service would be? I can do linux or windows and am relatively familiar with the lamp stack and IIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the Google App Engine for hosting, and writing the service in Java. I just set up a few services that way for an app I'm working on and it was fast and easy, and currently it's free of charge for a very generous limited usage.

Comment: It appears the Google App Engine is going to best easiest and best for what I plan to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if you are familiar with the lamp stack why not using php for the REST service? Check out [zend's REST implementation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.rest.server.html).

Answer (score 0):

Exposing REST type access to resources persisted as JPA entities is very straightforward with `Play! framework`:

- http://www.playframework.org
- [RESTful on Play! framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379485/restful-on-play-framework)

**Hosting:** `Heroku` ( http://www.heroku.com ) supports Java as a language (as well as Ruby, Node.js, Clojure, Python, and Scala), and `Play!` as a framework, making it a good candidate in case you are going the Play! route;-) ... though obviously not the only use case.

**Development life-cycle:** [This overview](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/) and [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database-driven-play-apps) should give you a pretty good feel of the development life-cycle with git and `Heroku`+`Play`; if coming from "regular" Java tooling type of environments, you may find this approach refreshing.

**IDE integration:** `Play!` has **plugins** for NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse ( http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/ide )