# How do I define an edit page within a REST API?

Tags: rest, playframework, routes, restful-url, url-design

In a Play app I'm designing, these are some of my routes

```
POST    /visits                     controllers.Visit.create
GET     /visits                     controllers.Visit.visits
GET     /visits/:id                 controllers.Visit.visit(id: Long)
PUT     /visits/:id                 controllers.Visit.update(id: Long)
DELETE  /visits/:id                 controllers.Visit.delete(id: Long)
```

I'm supporting a browser interface too.  I'm following with the guidance I saw here:
[RESTful on Play! framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379485/restful-on-play-framework)

I can easily provide an HTML template to display detailed information about one specific visit, or a list of visits.  But how does an "edit page" fall cleanly into this, which would have to be prefilled with the information from a particular visit?  I can easily do something like: `GET /visits/:id/edit controllers.Visit.edit(id: Long)` which would return a prefilled page with the visit information, or I can have a static HTML page which calls the `/visits/:id` with an AJAX call to populate the fields, and this would let me avoid corrupting my resource-driven API with a browser page-specific route.  Or is there some better option?  What is best practice and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In REST it doesn't make sense for you to create additional resources simply to perform standardized actions. Everyone who knows the HTTP protocol knows your visit object should be editable through a PATCH request with the diff you want to be applied, or through a PUT request that replaces the whole resource with a new one. Why create a custom and non-standard edit action with POST, that you will have to document and explain to everyone how it works?

In that sense, I'd say your best option is having a static HTML page that drives your API, using a GET on /visits/:id to populate the fields, and use the edited content to replace /visits/:id with a PUT when submitted.

However, keep in mind that there's nothing wrong with having a browser page-specific route in your API, as long as you're respecting the Accept header sent by the client. On my APIs, I sometimes have some routes returning a human friendly representation of the resource when the request is made using the Accept: text/html header, so it's a simple way to have a builtin admin client and the API can be easily explored with a browser. In REST, the only difference between an API and a WEB page is that the first returns a representation in a machine-friendly format, and the second a representation that you expect to be rendered by a browser in a human-friendly document. Both of them are supposed to have the links and/or forms with directions on how to edit the resource.

Comment: Awesome explanation.  One more question though.  You suggested an AJAX GET to populate the fields of my standard API, but then you suggest it's okay to have a browser page-specific route.  The browser page-specific route would allow me to avoid an extra client-server query, returning a pre-populated page.  Why WOULDN'T I want to do that?  Is there any argument for have the GET done with AJAX after the static page loads?  I'd imagine static page caching would be a huge win, and doing a browser page route would be best for..simple non-user facing admin pages, like you describe.  No?

Comment: The static document with AJAX acts as a client for your API, not as an API resource, and if you're careful to not couple it too much with one specific service, you can reuse it as an UI for all your APIs. Check the HAL-Browser, for instance. https://api-sandbox.foxycart.com/hal-browser/hal_browser.html#/. That's just an static html you can drop on any RESTful API driven by HAL, and it works as a browser for the whole API.