# Play framework websevice - activator start issue when passing the base64

Tags: java, web-services, post, playframework-2.0, base64

I am creating web-service APIs using the Play framework with Java. I have created the service successfully.

**WHAT I DID:**

In one web service request, I have sent the base64 string. If I passed the base64 string in the request, I got the below exception.

```
[warn] p.nettyException - Handling TooLongFrameException
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes.
```

After searching in the internet, I got the below solution.

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx3084m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=8192"
```

After setting the SBT_OPTS, I can pass the base64 string in the request and receive it on the server side successfully.

I used the following command for debugging purpose - `"activator -jvm-debug 9999 run"`. So it is working fine.

**WHAT IS ISSUE:**

But now I tried to deploy this as service. So that I used the following commands - `"activator start"` (or) `"activator start $SBT_OPTS"` (or) `"activator $SBT_OPTS start"`.

When I use this commands to start the service, I got the same above issue - `"An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes."`

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: @MonCalamari Thank you for the response. I did check the link. Can you tell me, Where do I set the http.netty.maxInitialLineLength?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line in your application.conf, then you don't need to set any config at runtime

parsers.text.maxLength=7024K

Its accept the request data upto 7MB, if you need more, you can set it.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaBodyParsers

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did set the parsers.text.maxLength. But still I did get the same issue. Can you please tell me, where do I set the http.netty.maxInitialLineLength?

Comment: You need to set it on application.conf, also please take a look "Max content length" in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaBodyParsers

Comment: I did set parsers.text.maxLength=7024K. But even I did get the issue "An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes".

Comment: Did you clean and compile the app after the changes you made?

Comment: Yes. I am using eclipse as IDE. So it is compiled the code once I clean the project. But still I am getting the issue. Can you help me to fix this.

Comment: [official doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/ja/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) parsers.text.maxLength is for body length. If you had error by URL length, set http.netty.maxInitialLineLength at System.Properties.