# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed Error on Invoking a DELETE method using WebServices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to delete a "Contact" from the "Contacts" table using the following @DELETE method (using Jersey Framework (JAX-RS implementation)

```
@DELETE
@Path("/delete/{contact}")
public String deleteContact(@PathParam("contact") String name) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String response = DAOaccess.deleteContact(name);
    return response; 
}
```

And the following url is used to invoke the webservice from the browser:

**/contacts/delete/contactname**

**But HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed** is thrown on doing so.

What might be the reason? How do I overcome this?

Comment: Is /contacts/delete/etc the right URL, ie as opposed to /delete/etc?

Comment: @MartinWilson I'm using @Path(/contacts) annotation at class level

Comment: Well, @DELETE means Delete HTTP method, right? And you are calling GET HTTP method, so, I think you should use another test method :)

Comment: @PlínioPantaleão Does that mean that I cant access a 'Delete' webservice method from the url? I did try by invoking the service via code, but that too is throwing an error.I have posted that as a separate question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670169/not-able-to-invoke-an-delete-web-service-in-rest-jersey

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**URL** = **/contacts/delete/contactname**

405 because

It seems delete is always behave as `submit (Post method)`
and you are trying to call as like `get` method from the `URL`.
`This is not possible to call the post method as like get`.
if you really want to call this web service from the browser to test, just download a `Mozilla plugin (Poster)` which will help you to submit the web service in your all method types.

Comment: I found this questions now in 2014 at one of top search results so I need to do a little update on this. There is a really good Client for the test of webservices. So feel free and have a look at: http://www.getpostman.com/ It's a really nice tool to simulate a web client.
You can add collections with every call you do and with every type you want - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) plugin to test your service. When you directly hit the URL from browser it goes as a `@GET` request which is not allowed in this case. [`RestClient`](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) is also available as standalone app. If you need more functionalities try `SoapUI`. I have also posted a response to your [question on `@DELETE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670169/not-able-to-invoke-an-delete-web-service-in-rest-jersey).