# HTTP Delete, Response Status: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: java, jax-rs

when sending http delete to my server this happens

```
Response Status: 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

header look like this

```
Date: Sat, 31 Jan 2015 19:17:47 GMT
Server: WildFly/8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Content-Length: 0
Allow: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
```

I suspect that I have to enable access to http delete method, but don't know how.

this is my delete method

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{id}")
public boolean deleteItem(@PathParam("id") long itemId);
```

this is the url for delete

```
wrong: http://192.168.2.101:8080/DataAccessRemoteWebapp/rest/dataitem/id=1

right: http://192.168.2.101:8080/DataAccessRemoteWebapp/rest/dataitem/1
```

I am using jax-rs

```
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
```

Comment: oh yeah you right >.<

Comment: Yes partly, with this I could test my delete method and I found out the method was wrong, so yeah Thx :D

Comment: Welcome. On a matter of Stack Overflow policy, rather than editing the answer into the question, it's better to post it as an answer. If someone with the same issue finds your question in a search, it won't be obvious that your "right:" in the question is the solution to the original question, unless they read the comments (which they shouldn't have to do). It's fine to post and accept an answer to your own question (or if someone solved it for you in a comment you could suggest they post it as an answer, which I'll do now). I suggest you revert your question edit in order to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The annotation `@Path("/{id})"` requires the `id` directly after the `/` and so it won't match your test URL

```
http://192.168.2.101:8080/DataAccessRemoteWebapp/rest/dataitem/id=1
```

Instead, remove the `id=`:

```
http://192.168.2.101:8080/DataAccessRemoteWebapp/rest/dataitem/1
```

Answer (score 2):

This old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673212/http-status-405-method-not-allowed-error-on-invoking-a-delete-method-using-web) on stackoverflow can respond to you question :

> URL = /contacts/delete/contactname
>
> 405 because
>
> It seems delete is always behave as submit (Post method) and you are
>   trying >to call as like get method from the URL. This is not possible
>   to call the >post method as like get. if you really want to call this
>   web service from >the browser to test, just download a Mozilla plugin
>   (Poster) which will help >you to submit the web service in your all
>   method types.

Comment: I am already using resteasy to test it with my browser and even there I get 405