# Is there a standard way in Spring to pass a body with a DELETE request to a REST endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am implementing a Spring client for an existing REST API and I need to invoke a DELETE while, at the same time, passing an access token in the request body, like this:

```
{ 
    "access_token": "..."
}
```

The problem is that, using the method that works for POST, the transmitted body is empty (I have intercepted the request body and made sure) and I cannot be authorised without this access token. This is what I am doing:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 UserRequest ur = new UserRequest(access_token);
 HttpEntity<UserRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<>(ur);                                               
 restTemplate.delete(url, entity);
```

I have no control over the API itself, so I don't have the option of passing the token as url parameter.

Is there a way to do this in Spring, or do I have to build my own HttpUrlConnection like described for instance in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075713)?

Comment: Cristina, Please, write the sample code how have you resolved it.

Comment: @TarasVovkovych Hmm, I'm afraid in the meantime I have another job, in another country, with other tools...but I'll check, perhaps I still have some backup code somewhere. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the RestTemplate object in Spring there's [an exchange method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-).

The parameters are :

- the url
- the method, in your case HttpMethod.DELETE
- the entity (with the body you have to transmit)
- the response type
- some object you could pass

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out!

Comment: Been trying the template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE,
                    requestEntity,
                    String.class) - doesn't work - the server doesn't see the income body, the delete(...) method doesn't work also