# jquery ajax request with json throwing parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have searched lot of on this issue and tried almost everything but it doesn't seem to be work so posting it here.

I am trying to make jquery ajax call to `ashx` handler by passing json data. But my request doesnt reach till handler `GetBalance.ashx`

code :

```
 var mydata = {};

$.ajax({
    url: 'Handlers/GetBalance.ashx?type=authenticateRequest',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: mydata,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

in console it prints

```
parsererror
(empty string)
```

What i am doing wrong ? It should reach till `.ashx` before it gives any response parse error

**Edit:**

*Changed as suggested by answer*

Comment: here you find the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468704/what-changed-in-jquery-1-9-to-cause-a-ajax-call-to-fail-with-syntax-error

Comment: could u post your ashx handler as well

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your developer tools. Do you see the HTTP request you expect? Do you see the HTTP response you expect?

Comment: The output you describe on the console looks like the results of the `error` function, as far as I know that won't run unless the request has hit your `.ashx` and get a response (with an error message in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line

```
data: mydata,
```

with

```
data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
contentType: "application/json",
```

Comment: try debugging by putting breakpoint in global.asax begin request method

Comment: try setting the content type