# HTTP status codes : 204 OR 200 with body containing an empty object?

Tags: http, web, rfc2616

I'm having trouble to understand the use cases of the 204 HTTP status code.
The RFC2616 says :

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document
>   view    from that which caused the request to be sent. This response
>   is    primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place
>   without    causing a change to the user agent's active document view,
>   although    any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to
>   the document    currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is
>   always    terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Does the "document view" refers to the DOM ?

If for instance, I fire an AJAX request deleting a user and I update my page to remove the user from a list once my request is successfully completed , should the server give me a 200 with a {} as a response or a 204 without a body ?

Edit : My main concern is related to the "If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent." part. To reformulate it with my own words : Can I update the DOM if I return a 204 ?

Comment: You really ought to read the current RFC which has updated prose on this, see http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7231.html#status.204

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the "document view" refers to the DOM ?

Not exactly, it means the rendered document. DOM is not a representation of the rendered document. It is is abstract model of the documents tree. Each UA may render it differently.

> I fire an AJAX request deleting a user and I update my page to remove
>   the user from a list once my request is successfully completed ,
>   should the server give me a 200 with a {} as a response or a 204
>   without a body?

This depends on the API and how 'conformant' it is. So, if you submitted a delete request using the 'DELETE' verb (so, its a RESTful API), then the response should be 200 OK; but it can also send a 204 if the API is especially pedantic.

If you are just sending a GET request to '/some/view?id=1&action=delete', it will *most likely* return 200 OK

In either case, you are free to change the DOM (and thus, trigger a re-rendering of the document) because of the second part:

> although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the
>   document currently in the user agent's active view.

So, using <strike>`<strike>`</strike> to indicate that the record has been deleted would conform to this requirement.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds silly but the metainformation mentionned in the RFC are <META> tags in the header right ? So I'm free to update these but not information the <body> ?

Comment: If you are writing the server part, then yes. If you are writing the client part - then you won't change these because they will be set from the server as part of the response.

Answer (score 7):

Both are actually valid. It all depends of your application.

A valid deletion can return both 200 or 204 response code.

The document view does refer to the DOM, yes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete) talks about it.