# RESTful API should I return a message after adding or deleting a record?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I would like to know if it a good practice (and really useful for a front end developer) return a message after adding or deleting a records using a RESTful API or if the status code 200 is enough.

At the moment I am sending a message only in case of error example (404 Bad Request):

```
{
message: "The request is invalid."
modelState: {
locationId: [1]
0:  "LocationId is invalid. Make sure LocationId exists and it is in the right format."
-
}-
}
```

With message(200)

```
{
message: "all ok"
}
```

Notes: I am using ApiController in asp.net MVC.

Comment: 404 Bad Request? - it should be 404 Not Found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete

Answer (score 2):

A 200 response indicates there was no problem with the request.
For a DELETE, you could also use a 204 - No Content - Which implies the request was received, but I've nothing to say about it.

In the case of a POST, you could also return the newly resource in the body of the response.