# API Rest Update/Insert/Delete return in Asp Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to know what is the best return to do with CRUD opérations in ASP core?

I'm using an AngularJS front, so I don't use redirectToAction() etc

So what are the best practice ?

For example for an update should I return "NoContentResult()" or Something else? Thanks

Comment: After re-reading your question i'm not too sure that my answer is on-topic ... please let me know if i missed the point of your question so i can update my answer accordingly :-)

Comment: No it's ok you helped me thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ultimate-every-case "best" return. You need to return what makes sense.

If the user tires to delete an entity that, for example, does not exist you should return a `NotFound()` (404) so there won't be a content body here. You can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342589/6838730) for more info about which HTTP code makes sense. You can also use [this page](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) which lists http codes and their meaning to decide what makes sense in your case.

Rest is strongly based on status code so whatever you return, it should simply make sense from an HTTP point of view. Return a content body only if it makes sense and a HTTP code that matches the result of the operation.

The above is general good practices. To answer your question, I'd say that it's up to you. You can chose to return an empty content with `NoContentResult()` or you can return the update entity. It all depends on what will be useful to the API's consumer.