# What status code for ressource that may or may not exist on REST API

Tags: php, angular, rest, http

I am working on a one page web application for an online shop in Angular which will rely on a REST API handled by Symfony. One of the first request I make is that I need to know if the customer has an active cart or not. So I have a route /get-user-cart which returns null if the user has no cart (then I display a button to create a cart), if the user has an active cart I return the cart and its content.

My question is what HTTP code should I return if the user has no cart? Should I return a 200 code (the server answered correctly and the response is null) or a 404 content not found code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP status code for update and delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete)

Comment: `200` looks correct.

Comment: Sorry i don't think the link answers to it, first it's a get and not put or delete. Second the fact that there is no cart is not an error per say. There is no cart is as valid as here is your cart.

Comment: Most sites don't really require you to *create* a cart. Why not just return 200 with an empty array to indicate the cart is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should return 200 status code with null response.
Since cart is not a resource, Where as each of the  contents inside carts can be considered as resource.

Comment: cart can be considered as a property of the resource user. In your case resources are 1. User 2. Products

Answer (score -1):

I would return a 404.

Think that you are requesting an object (the user cart) to te API and the object does not exists.

Comment: Yes but i am not specifically requesting a cart, i am asking does a cart exist and if it does please return it to me.

Comment: Yes, that's really a point of view. But what you are really requesting is "Give me the cart of the current user" is like "Give me the cart with id XXX" but the id is implicit in the user session. Returning a 404 you are saying to your app "This resource does not exists" and then you can create it (witht a POST request), but returning a 200 response with null you are saying "This resource exists but is empty"

Comment: @DavidRojo I don't understand why someone downvoted you. This is the correct answer. also the OP uses the endpoint getFoo rather than findFoo. Find can yield empty results, but get can only return an object or throw an exception, in this case, a 404

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404