# What would be the status code if a put request has no error but not updating any thing?

Tags: database, http, backend, rest, http-status-codes

I created an put api and it takes updated object, But what I need to update is already available in the document. Though it doesn't create any change it returns with status code 200. What may be the suitable status code for this case ?

Comment: Check out this answer from Daniel Vassallo and iliketocode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342589/15746224

Comment: But here is not defined anything if it not modify this specific document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it from the other way round: What's the status code, for if a PUT request made an actual alteration (say update or created a record in a database, e.g.)? It's `201 – Created`.

So `200` is actually the right status code here. But in your situation I'd test, that actual alterations result in a `2xx` different from the (idempotent) `200 - Ok`.

Comment: Do you think 204 is suitable for not updating any document though there was no error and also the document was found ?

Comment: If the document was found, there was no error and no changes were made, the appropriate response would be either 200 or 304