# When call fetch on php controller then it fails on json()

Tags: php, reactjs, json

I have this error from ReactJS:

```
VM345:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Short summary:
I have php controller with delete end point - below piece of code.

**php code**

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    error_log('green options');
    return;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') {

    http_response_code(204);   //http code for DELETE 
    // http_response_code(404);
    $jsonData = json_encode([
        "message" => "Product not found"
    ]);
    error_log($jsonData);
    print $jsonData;

}
```

Then I call this end point from reactJS via below code but it fails on this error that I cannot understand. Any other end points (GET, POST) work as expected. Maybe it is related somehow with OPTIONS method because it is passed only in case of DELETE method.

EDIT: Is there any way how to check it from chrome debug? When I debug only response variable then I am not possible to see any content. Thanks

**react code**

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'DELETE',
    mode: 'cors',
};
fetch(URL + id, requestOptions).then(response => {
    return response.json(); //here it fails
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT:

Chrome - Network - developer tools
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the browser's Developer Tools to monitor the fetch() request in the network tool. Click on the request after it triggers, and go to the Reaponse tab in there to see exactly what response was returned by php. Meanwhile if there is a CORS error, that would be visible in the Console after the request has completed

Comment: There was no CORS error after I used this one ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') ...

Comment: But if it _is_ an OPTIONS request (again, the network tool will show you this), then your php code does not return a response, which could easily then cause that JSON error. I suggest at least returning an empty object as JSON, so there is something to parse

Comment: I added screenshot with response variable from Developer Tools

Comment: OK but did you also check what I suggested in the network tool?

Comment: I also added screenshot with Network tab. You can see two requests - OPTIONS, DELETE. What can I check there? I guess that Response tab should display some content like in case other GET request? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

I finally fount out that the issue is related to returned http code 204.
When I change it to 200 then it works well.
I have no clue why it caused this kind of issues but that's the way it is.

Any clue in any way?

The http code 200 or 204 can be used to identify 'resource was deleted'.
[HTTP status code for update and delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342579/http-status-code-for-update-and-delete)

Comment: Ah of course...204 means "No Content" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) so regardless if the server sends a response or not, I think fetch() maybe assumes it didn't, so then if you try to parse that response as JSON, inevitably it fails because, as far as fetch() is concerned, there was nothing to parse. "200 OK" is perfectly acceptable as a response to indicate that everything succeeded.